# LEA Networks NetSocket AV200 and LEA Networks NetPlug AV200 interconnectivity

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I have a pair of [LEA Networks NetPlug AV200 Advanced Chipset 200Mbps PLC Adapter Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EOSMT8U). I love that they give me approximately the same speed in 2 of my most used rooms in the house.

Now, I would like to expand to another room, but the same NetPlugs are not available. The ones that are available,are [LEA Networks NetSocket AV200 200Mbps PLC Adapter Kit w/Filtered Outlet (2 HPAV Units)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XB6WKPI)

The question really is, will these work with each other, so that I can have my entire house covered?

Note that I do not live in the US, so it very difficult for me to buy them and return back, so trying it out, is a little bit of a problem.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
-Bijal

Answer (score 0):

Both devices follow the HomePlug AV specification (and even use the same chipset), so yes, they should work together.

(There are three largest powerline networking standards – HomePlug (nearly gone by now), HomePlug AV (with interoperable AV200 and AV500 variants), and G.hn; as long as you check that all your purchases follow the *same* standard, they should work fine. Although I've been advised to stick to the same manufacturer if I can...)